# Getting multiple broadcasts from intents?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

I used the example code in the above link my own application for sending an SMS, but I run into a problem when checking the sent status of my message. What happens is, the toast message will pop up for every message I have attempted to send. So basically, let's say I've already sent 3 messages. When I go to send my 4th message, the toast message will pop up 4 times. It seems that perhaps the BroadcastReceiver is receiving the same broadcast from every intent used so far? I cannot figure out exactly why this is happening, or how to stop it. Any help or insights will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the specific method that causes this:

```
 //---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post the complete minimal code necessary to replicate the problem?

Comment: I'll edit my original post to include the method that causes the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you have a `new BroadcastReceiver(){` every time you call `sendSMS`, so they pile up, one more each time you call `sendSMS`. You could add `unregister(this);` at the bottom of each `BroadcastReceiver` but better would be to move the Broadcast receiver out of this function. You can **create+register** one in `onResume()` and `unregister` it in `onPause().`

Second, read this [link](http://www.gauntface.co.uk/pages/blog/2010/01/04/proximity-alerts-in-android/)
if you ever want to send data along with your `pendingIntent` you need to help Android distinguish your pending intents better ... 
**e.g.**

```
 PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, uniqueIdPerSMS++,
    new Intent(DELIVERED), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Hello I faced the same problem I have 1 broadcast receiver from that I started 1 service which is for getting messages from inbox. After that from that service I send those messages to the particular number. And for the sending message I used the same code as above(posted by John). My problem is, when I send message the toast Message "SMS SENT" will come continuously. So how can I receive that only once?

Comment: Hello, I'm using more or less the same code but the thing is I want to recieve update for each sent/delievered SMS.
and for differentiating that I'm adding some data to Intent (the no on which sms was sent) but on every received broadcase I receive the same(only the no which was added at first place) data. Any help would be really appricable . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple this is that use a unique id for each deliveredPI, because if you do not then android considers all the same and for  all the sms's the deliveredPi will show the result of any one( do not know if first or last).