# Android sms intent bundle toast info not updating

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, toast

I am sending 2 sms messages, i want to have 2 toast messages with

1) "SMS sent - first number" and

2) "SMS sent - second number"

however, am getting 2 toast messages both showing message

1), what happen to message

2)? what's missing?

thanks.

```
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent - " + arg1.getStringExtra("SendTo"), 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    Intent intent = new Intent(SENT);
    intent.putExtra("SendTo", "first number");
    PendingIntent sentIntents = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    sms.sendTextMessage("1234", null, message, sentIntents, null);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(SENT);
    intent1.putExtra("SendTo", "second number");
    PendingIntent sentIntents1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent1, 0);
    sms.sendTextMessage("456", null, message, sentIntents1, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is -using the same intent.So you have to update the intents and change the request code so that result not overlapped .
See the following.Following code will work.

```
 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent - " + arg1.getStringExtra("SendTo"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SENT);
            intent.putExtra("SendTo", "first number");
            PendingIntent sentIntents = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            sms.sendTextMessage("5556", null,message, sentIntents, null);

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(SENT);
            intent1.putExtra("SendTo", "second number");
            PendingIntent sentIntents1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            sms.sendTextMessage("5556", null, message, sentIntents1, null);
```

Comment: thanks!! just the right medicine.

btw, just dug some more and found this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180229/getting-multiple-broadcasts-from-intents

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "First number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
sms.sendTextMessage("1234", null, message, null, null);
Toast.makeText(this, "Second number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
sms.sendTextMessage("456", null, message, mull, null);
```

Comment: i want it such that toast should only show if sent is successful