# SMS BroadCast Receiver receives many times?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am using sms broadcast receiver in my application. When i send first sms it popups one message as sms sent. when i sent second request the popup message get doubled. In third time it tripled and so on. I am using following code for sending and receiving the broadcast.

```
  private void sendRequest()
    {        
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid PhoneNumber", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            } 
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));


       SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(sms_phonenumber, null, sms_message, sentPI, null);
```

I am not sure y this is happening. I am sending sms message from mainactivity.

Thanks for your help guys..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks because every time you call `sendRequest` you register `BroadcastReceiver` one more time ........

you should register the `BroadcastReceiver` once only and that should be unregistered before living the activity........

do register and unregistered work once only in `onStart` and `onStop`  as in [link](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/11/create-our-own-service-and.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. if you could please let me know how to unregister for the above code..

Comment: do register and unregistered work once only in onStart and onStop  ... http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/11/create-our-own-service-and.html

Comment: or put the BroadcastReceiver in XML http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: ohh I got some thing for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180229/getting-multiple-broadcasts-from-intents