# Saving Incoming and Outgoing Call details on Server (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, incoming-call

I want to save the Incoming and outgoing call on server automatically. I want written code but sometime it works and sometime my app get crashed.. Can anyone Help me to solve this. Below is my CallReceiver.java code:

```
public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context context;
String currentDateTimeString;
String state;
String number;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    //this.context = context;
    state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if(state==null){
        //outgoing call
        number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.i("tag", "Outgoing number : " +number);
        currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        Log.i("tag", "Date :" + currentDateTimeString);
        doSaveCallRecord(1);


    }
    else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
    {
        //incoming call
        number=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Log.i("tag","Incoming number : "+number);
        currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        Log.i("tag", "Date :" + currentDateTimeString);
        doSaveCallRecord(0);
    }
}

public static String getContactName(Context context,String phoneNumber){
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));

        Toast.makeText(context,"Name :"+contactName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactName;
}
```

Comment: where you are getting error?...and what error?  post the log cat.

Comment: I have Changed code now. I am getting Outgoing number now and incoming also but now the problem is i am getting number 2-3 times.

Comment: take a look at this... [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8413512/3790052]

Comment: and this.. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11031249/3790052]

Comment: Should i write my incoming call detial code in if (activeNetInfo != null) {
            if(firstConnect) { 
                // do subroutines here
                firstConnect = false;
            }

Comment: first try to run on some other devices... to check if it is the actual issue.